# Unable to see device on MaaS

Tags: boot, maas, pxe, canonical

I tried to PXE boot an Intel NUC using a MaaS server and got the following message:

```
cloud-init[1498]: Can not apply stage final, no datasource found! Likely bad things to come!
```

After this message is displayed, a login prompt appears asking me for a username and password. However, nothing shows up on my MaaS server's web interface (no devices listed, no deployable nodes etc.).

My questions:

1. Why doesn't the Intel NUC show up on MaaS? Do I have to configure MaaS for PXE booting? If so, where do I do this? I can't seem to find specific PXE boot settings on the web interface.
2. I tried booting other desktops I have as well and these do show up on MaaS as non-deployable (they show up under `Devices` and not `Machines`). Why are these computers not deployable? I have set up SSH Keys and the computers have been configured to PXE boot.
3. What is the default username and password given to clients so I can login to the Intel NUC?

Comment: any update on this...? I am kinda stuck on the same issue .. 
Any leads would be really helpful

Comment: I manged to get nodes to show up on MaaS after starting from scratch again (re-installed OS and MaaS). I don't recall what I did differently since this was a while ago.

Comment: thanks for the reply mate...!! my issue got solved , its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the repository on maas and you must update and upgrade the MAAS server.